# EnterCriticalSection Deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock

Having what appears to be a dead-lock situation with a multi-threaded logging application.

Little background:

My main application has 4-6 threads running.  The main thread responsible for monitoring health of various things I'm doing, updating GUIs, etc... Then I have a transmit thread and a receive thread.  The transmit and receive threads talk to physical hardware.  I sometimes need to debug the data that the transmit and receive threads are seeing; i.e. print to a console without interrupting them due to their time critical nature of the data.  The data, by the way, is on a USB bus.

Due to the threading nature of the application, I want to create a debug console that I can send messages to from my other threads.  The debug consule runs as a low priority thread and implements a ring buffer such that when you print to the debug console, the message is quickly stored to a ring buffer and sets and event.  The debug console's thread sits WaitingOnSingleObject events from the in bound messages that come in.  When an event is detected, console thread updates a GUI display with the message.  Simple eh?  The printing calls and the console thread use a critical section to control access.

NOTE:  I can adjust the ring buffer size if I see that I am dropping messages (at least that's the idea).

In a test application, the console works very well if I call its Print method slowly via mouse clicks.  I have a button that I can press to send messages to the console and it works.  However, if I put any sort of load (many calls to Print method), everything dead-locks.  When I trace the dead-lock, my IDE's debugger traces to EnterCriticalSection and sits there.

NOTE:  If I remove the Lock/UnLock calls and just use Enter/LeaveCriticalSection (see the code) I sometimes work but still find myself in a dead-lock situation.  To rule out deadlocks to stack push/pops, I call Enter/LeaveCriticalSection directly now but this did not solve my issue....  What's going on here?

Here is one Print statement, that allows me to pass in a simple int to the display console.

```
void TGDB::Print(int I)
{
    //Lock();
    EnterCriticalSection(&CS);

    if( !SuppressOutput )
    {
        //swprintf( MsgRec->Msg, L"%d", I);
        sprintf( MsgRec->Msg, "%d", I);
        MBuffer->PutMsg(MsgRec, 1);
    }

    SetEvent( m_hEvent );
    LeaveCriticalSection(&CS);
    //UnLock();
}

// My Lock/UnLock methods
void TGDB::Lock(void)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&CS);
}

bool TGDB::TryLock(void)
{
    return( TryEnterCriticalSection(&CS) );
}

void TGDB::UnLock(void)
{
        LeaveCriticalSection(&CS);
}

// This is how I implemented Console's thread routines

DWORD WINAPI TGDB::ConsoleThread(PVOID pA)
{
DWORD rVal;

         TGDB *g = (TGDB *)pA;
        return( g->ProcessMessages() );
}

DWORD TGDB::ProcessMessages()
{
DWORD rVal;
bool brVal;
int MsgCnt;

    do
    {
        rVal = WaitForMultipleObjects(1, &m_hEvent, true, iWaitTime);

        switch(rVal)
        {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:

                EnterCriticalSection(&CS);
                //Lock();

                if( KeepRunning )
                {
                    Info->Caption = "Rx";
                    Info->Refresh();
                    MsgCnt = MBuffer->GetMsgCount();

                    for(int i=0; i<MsgCnt; i++)
                    {
                        MBuffer->GetMsg( MsgRec, 1);
                        Log->Lines->Add(MsgRec->Msg);
                    }
                }

                brVal = KeepRunning;
                ResetEvent( m_hEvent );
                LeaveCriticalSection(&CS);
                //UnLock();

            break;

            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                EnterCriticalSection(&CS);
                //Lock();
                Info->Caption = "Idle";
                Info->Refresh();
                brVal = KeepRunning;
                ResetEvent( m_hEvent );
                LeaveCriticalSection(&CS);
                //UnLock();
            break;

            case WAIT_FAILED:
                EnterCriticalSection(&CS);
                //Lock();
                brVal = false;
                Info->Caption = "ERROR";
                Info->Refresh();
                aLine.sprintf("Console error: [%d]", GetLastError() );
                Log->Lines->Add(aLine);
                aLine = "";
                LeaveCriticalSection(&CS);
                //UnLock();
            break;
        }

    }while( brVal );

    return( rVal );
}
```

MyTest1 and MyTest2 are just two test functions that I call in response to a button press.  MyTest1 never causes a problem no matter how fast I click the button.  MyTest2 dead locks nearly everytime.

```
// No Dead Lock
void TTest::MyTest1()
{
    if(gdb)
    {
        // else where: gdb = new TGDB;
        gdb->Print(++I);
    }
}


// Causes a Dead Lock
void TTest::MyTest2()
{
    if(gdb)
    {
        // else where: gdb = new TGDB;
        gdb->Print(++I);
        gdb->Print(++I);
        gdb->Print(++I);
        gdb->Print(++I);
        gdb->Print(++I);
        gdb->Print(++I);
        gdb->Print(++I);
        gdb->Print(++I);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Found a bug in my ring buffer implementation.  Under heavy load, when buffer wrapped, I didn't detect a full buffer properly so buffer was not returning.  I'm pretty sure that issue is now resolved.  Once I fixed the ring buffer issue, performance got much better.  However, if I decrease the iWaitTime, my dead lock (or freeze up issue) returns.

So after further tests with a much heavier load it appears my deadlock is not gone. Under super heavy load I continue to deadlock or at least my app freezes up but no where near it use to since I fixed ring buffer problem.  If I double the number of Print calls in MyTest2 I easily can lock up every time....

Also, my updated code is reflected above.  I know make sure my Set & Reset event calls are inside critical section calls.

Comment: Offtopic: I wonder why the code doesn't highlight? It does in edit-view... Well it does sometimes, anyway. =/

Comment: highlights for me... Maybe try clearing browser cache and restarting?

Comment: You can run this in a debugger right? Where are the threads when it "deadlocks" ?

Comment: yes, I can run this in a debugger and I can also run it in my main code base so long as I don't hit with any sort of load; i.e. calling the TDGB::Print method inside a for loop or in succession.  Please see my two test functions (MyTest1 & MyTest2).  In the debugger, I get to the EnterCriticalSection and hang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With those options closed up, I would ask questions about this "Info" object. Is it a window, which window is it parented to, and which thread was it created on?

If Info, or its parent window, was created on the other thread, then the following situation might occur:

The Console Thread is inside a critical section, processing a message.
The Main thread calls Print() and blocks on a critical section waiting for the Console Thread to release the lock.
The Console thread calls a function on Info (Caption), which results in the system *sending* a message (WM_SETTEXT) to the window. SendMessage blocks because the target thread is not in a message alertable state (isn't blocked on a call to GetMessage/WaitMessage/MsgWaitForMultipleObjects).

Now you have a deadlock.

This kind of #$(%^ can happen whenever you mix blocking routines with anything that interacts with windows. The only appropriate blocking function to use on a GUI thread is MSGWaitForMultipleObjects otherwise SendMessage calls to windows hosted on the thread can easily deadlock.

Avoiding this involves two possible approaches:

- Never doing any GUI interaction in worker threads. Only use PostMessage to dispatch non blocking UI update commands to the UI thread, OR
- Use kernel Event objects + MSGWaitForMultipleObjects (on the GUI thread) to ensure that even when you are blocking on a resource, you are still dispatching messages.

Comment: ya know, this probably very correct!  I've done a lot with multi-threading and I have no problems else where; only here where I call into Windows UI.  The UI, by the way, are Embarcadero VCL components.  I suspect the core thread has blocked the SendMessage as you've suggested.  Off to go test this...

Comment: yup, sure enough that was it.  I simply disable the GUI calls and dump my ring buffer or if I simply comment out all the GUI calls within the case WAIT_OBJECT_0: and dump the buffer on timeout, everything works now.  Thanks for hanging in there to help highlight this, Chris!  I'm quite interested in Ben Voigt's comments that I think I'll investigate.  I found a code project demo that provides a reference implementation.  Interim I'll look at the MSGWaitForMultipleObjects - a new API call for me.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing where it is deadlocking this code is hard to figure out. Two comments tho:

- Given that this is c++, you should be using an Auto object to perform the lock and unlock. Just in case it ever becomes non catastrophic for Log to throw an exception.
- You are resetting the event in response to WAIT_TIMEOUT. This leaves a small window of opportunity for a 2nd Print() call to set the event while the worker thread has returned from WaitForMultiple, but before it has entered the critical section. Which will result in the event being reset when there is actually data pending.

But you do need to debug it and reveal where it "Deadlocks". If one thread IS stuck on EnterCriticalSection, then we can find out why. If neither thread is, then the incomplete printing is just the result of an event getting lost.

Comment: This information helped me unrelated to the core issue.  Root cause, I found, was within my ring buffer.  The ring buffer had a bug and was not returning so the dead lock was not really a dead lock by definition.  My ring buffer simply was not returning.  Once I fixed that bug, everything began working.  I'm marking this the correct answer since it pointed out a potential problem within the WAIT_TIMEOUT case.  Thank you!

Comment: just a note for anyone that is interested.  My ring buffer was getting data so fast, that an edge case where the buffer had wrapped and my R/W pointers (Read pointer and Write pointers keep track of where I am in the ring) within became equal and ringbuffer code upon a new write when R/W pointer was equal looked like a full buffer again.  Likewise a write looked like an empty buffer.  So read-full or write empty caused buffer to dead lock at this edge case.  Once corrected, my "deadlock" went away.

Comment: Ah, crap... after further tests it appears my deadlock is not gone.  Under super heavy load I continue to deadlock or at least my app freezes up but no where near it use to since I fixed ring buffer problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend a lockfree implementation.

Not only will this avoid potential deadlock, but **debug instrumentation is one place where you absolutely do not want to take a lock**.  The impact of formatting debug messages on timing of a multi-threaded application is bad enough... having locks synchronize your parallel code just because you instrumented it makes debugging futile.

What I suggest is an SList-based design (The Win32 API provides an SList implementation, but you can build a thread-safe template easily enough using InterlockedCompareExchange and InterlockedExchange).  Each thread will have a pool of buffers.  Each buffer will track the thread it came from, after processing the buffer, the log manager will post the buffer back to the source thread's SList for reuse.  Threads wishing to write a message will post a buffer to the logger thread.  This also prevents any thread from starving other threads of buffers.  An event to wake the logger thread when a buffer is placed into the queue completes the design.

Comment: interesting!!!  In my defense, this debug console is not something that is typically active.  It requires a special command line switch to turn it on and then, only certain things get logged via a hidden window used to select what to log.  It's a logging system only to be called upon when I need to print from temporary code, enabled code from hidden UI selection, etc.... But very interested in your thoughts in other areas I do use critical sections.  Might you have good source to recommend to read up on?

Comment: Using critical sections in other areas is fine, if that's what you understand.  But critical sections (or any kind of lock including ones buried in the allocator or I/O layer) in debug code is a disaster (a software version of Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle).  As far as resources to learn more, I'd suggest that you look through the [`comp.programming.threads` archives](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.programming.threads/topics).  I learned a lot from some of the same experts before Microsoft killed the MS public newsgroups.