# How to avoid this deadlock between a critical section and SendMessage?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, deadlock

I am fixing a bug in code, and scratching my head at the best way to solve it. Here is how this deadlock occurs:

1. Worker thread acquires a resource lock.
2. GUI thread tries to acquire the same resource lock, and blocks.
3. Worker thread uses `SendMessage` to the GUI thread, and thus blocks.

The resource being locked is a big data structure about network status - including a list of users, their profile info, etc.

Avoiding the `SendMessage` call is not realistic, unfortunately. It's too much impact on the program change to something asynchronous to the GUI here.

My instinct is that I should aim to **avoid locks in the GUI thread**. The GUI thread only needs read access to the data it's locking. This would solve this deadlock, and would probably fix other response time problems in the app. Is this a good instinct?

To do this, I feel the GUI should work with a *copy* of the data it needs to access, avoiding the need to lock anything at all.

So, **how do I get this copy?** If I create the copy from the GUI thread, then I must use a lock again, and I haven't solved anything. But how else can I do this?

Or....... is my approach entirely wrong? What is the best way to fix this bug?

---

Edit: found a similar question: [EnterCriticalSection Deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042076/entercriticalsection-deadlock)

Some possible solutions:

- Don't use blocking GUI calls from worker threads -- use `PostMessage` instead.
- If the GUI code that acquires the lock is triggered by a worker, then copy the resource from the worker, and pass the heap pointer to the GUI. This way the GUI doesn't need to lock anything. This *is* the case for my code, so I will try this.
- Use `TryEnterCriticalSection` in the GUI, and if I couldn't enter, then resume message pumping and just schedule another try later, maybe with `PostMessage`.
- Remove locks around calls to `SendMessage` in workers.

Comment: Don't use SendMessage, use PostMessage or direct calls

Comment: Is it possible for your worker to release resource before sending message to GUI? Is it possible for you GUI to work with copy was made earlier if resource is blocked, else make fresh cope and work?

Comment: @paulm: as I said, it's too much impact to switch from SendMessage to an async call. vard: I will look into this.

Comment: @tenfour does your message from worker to gui serves notifying GUI it needs to update itself?

Comment: What kind of read access is the lock on the GUI side guarding? If it's only for something like displaying, it could just try to acquire the mutext (e.g. `TryEnterCriticalSection()`) and if that does not happen, reschedule the view update later (queue another paint message or whatever).

Comment: vard: The messages are for a bunch of different purposes that do need to be synchronous. @Yirkha: that's a really good idea.

Comment: If you *know* that a worker thread has acquired the CS and is not otherwise doing anything else but waiting for SendMessage() to complete then there is no need to also acquire the CS in the UI thread.  You ought to be able to know at least a little bit, given that this code started running in the window procedure.  You get the required memory barrier for free.  How the SendMessage call ended up getting marshaled is pretty murky btw, that's normally only done for system messages.

Comment: @HansPassant: good point, but the GUI is already blocking at this point. It goes like this: worker locks, gui locks, worker `SendMessage`. So the gui is already blocking at this point. After thinking about this more ... I feel that the worst part of this whole system is the dependence on `SendMessage` from worker threads. I am going to seriously try to switch to `PostMessage`, and otherwise I will try the other recommendations.

Comment: Acquiring a synchronization object and then entering the message loop is indeed a very good way to cause trouble.  Strongly favor only pumping messages when your UI thread is a quiescent state.  If a worker thread needs to back off because the UI thread is not in a state to process a message then that needs to be negotiated separately.  With, say, TryEnterCriticalSection(), sleep if that fails.

Comment: Don't call SendMessage while you have the resource locked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using PostMessage instead of SendMessage will avoid the deadlock. There are two ways you could do that. If you do not want to copy the data then the GUI thread message handler will have to acquire the lock to access the data. So there will be contention, but no deadlock. To avoid all contention you would have to make a copy of the data in the worker thread. Use 'new' to put the copy in the heap. Then pass the heap pointer as a parameter of the PostMessage call. The GUI thread can access the data copy, then it should delete the passed pointer.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of operation is the lock guarding on the GUI side? If it's only for something like displaying, it would probably not matter if the operation was done a few dozen milliseconds later.

So could only *try* to acquire the mutex (e.g. `TryEnterCriticalSection()`) instead of waiting for it, and if it is not available, reschedule the update later (invalidate the window again to trigger another paint message, queue a custom update message or whatever).